# How can I divide an Xparse generated list by "section-like" environments?

Tags: lists, xparse, answers

I mostly use the `xparse` library to create organized lists. Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newcounter{quest}
\newcommand{\quest}{\noindent\stepcounter{quest}{\bf Q}{\bf \arabic{quest}.\ }}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\answer}{ m }{ \malmedal_input_add:n { #1 } }
\NewDocumentCommand{\listanswers}{ }{ \malmedal_output_direct: }

\seq_new:N \g_malmedal_input_seq
\seq_new:N \l_malmedal_temp_seq
\int_new:N \l_malmedal_count_int

\cs_new:Npn \malmedal_input_add:n #1
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_malmedal_input_seq { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \malmedal_output_direct:
 {
  \int_zero:N \l_malmedal_count_int
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_malmedal_input_seq
   {
    \int_incr:N \l_malmedal_count_int
    \malmedal_print:n { ##1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \malmedal_print:n #1
 {
  \noindent{\textbf{Question } ~ \bfseries\int_to_arabic:n { \l_malmedal_count_int }} ~ : ~ #1 \par
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Math}
\quest $1 + 1 = ?$
\answer{$2$.}

\quest If $a = 2$ and $b = 5$, then $a - b = ?$
\answer{$-3$.}

\quest Are there any natural numbers between $8$ and $9$?
\answer{No.}

\section{Physics}
\quest What's the speed of light in vacuum?
\answer{$\approx 3\cdot 10^8$ m/s}

\quest Name one thing one can't do without atmospheric pressure.
\answer{To drink water with a straw.}
\section{Answer Key}

\listanswers
\end{document}
```

This generates:

[image]

I was wondering if there's a way to divide that generated list by each of the sections, as below:

[image]

And please, if you do want to help, don't just say there's a simpler way to generate Answer Keys. I need a solution within xparse package. Thanks already!

Comment: Given that you're using stuff developed for LaTeX 3, isn't it time to give up macros rendered obsolete by LaTeX 2e? `\bf` is 20+ years deprecated and ought not be used in LaTeX documents created or updated after that date.

Comment: You could add each section to the list of answers and then modify `\malmedal_output_direct:` to test whether it is an answer or not and respond accordingly. You can't divide the generated list according to sections as it is because there's no way of figuring out how the section divisions fall within the list. Unless this is predictable, of course.

Comment: There are easier ways to do this and, to be honest, I can't tell from your question what the real constraints are.

Comment: So you think I should give up on these macros and try to get more on Latex 3 (honest question)?

Comment: The only xparse commands in your example are \answers and \listofanswers. The rest of the code is expl3, and if you want an expl3 solution you could use http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets which is written completly in expl3. Beside this it is easy to implement such a split: Simply record for each answer also the current section number and name (e.g. through a label) and then use this for tests.

Comment: It happened exactly what I said it would: "there are easier ways". I'm not criticizing, really, I appreciate the act of trying to help me. But I asked for a substantial answer. And of course, I know that one can manage any problem by himself. That's why it's called a "help", 'cuz I've already tried a lot, and haven't moved forward on this subject. But again, thanks anyway.